# Making icon for a Windows Form: How to make it show up correctly?

Tags: winforms, icons

OK, so I have built a Windows Form application.  I now want an icon for it.  So I use the Icon Editor built into Visual Studio 2012.  Draw it all out to look nice and purdy.  Once I am done, I have a .ico file and I make it the default icon for the project, and also the icon for the one WinForm in the application.

Unfortunately, it does not show up as I have created it!  It is displayed as the default icon file as it existed before I modified it in the icon editor.  It's a 32x32 4 bit icon.  If I change the extension to .bmp it shows up as the default.

It looks like the VS icon editor is editing something else, not the appearance of the icon.  Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

I used to have a progam called IconArt that would create icons that looked like icons when I used them in VS.  IconArt is now abandonware and won't run on my 64bit Windows workstation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I didn't get any answers within the time I was hoping, I posted this question also in the MSDN Visual Studio forum, and got a good answer that I thought I should post here.  Credit to [Reed Copsey, Jr](http://reedcopsey.com/), for the answer!

This is it:

> You'll need to put your design in all of the different versions.  ICO
>   files contain multiple versions of the same image, for different
>   screen resolutions.
>
> My personal preference is to not use VS - there's an ICO plugin for
>   Paint.Net (all free) which allows you to make a single image
>   (typically 256x256), and save multiple versions within an ICO file in
>   one shot.  It's very useful for building icons.
>
> See
>   http://forums.getpaint.net/index.php?/topic/927-icon-cursor-and-animated-cursor-format-v37-may-2010/
>   for the plugin.

Since I am a Paint.Net user, the plugin sounded like a great idea, and I tried it.  Bingo!  This works very nicely.